# ArrayList data passed to a second Activity is not showing in a TableLayout there

Tags: android, android-intent, arraylist, android-tablelayout

I'm trying to send a sample `ArrayList` to a second `Activity` so that it can be displayed in a `TableLayout`.

My `MainActivity` class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<>();
    Button b;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    al.add("Add");
                    al.add("Sub");
                    Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(),two.class);
                    i.putStringArrayListExtra("al", al);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
    }
}
```

The `activity_main` layout contains a `Button` that opens the next `Activity`, which contains a `TableLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:stretchColumns="0,1"
        android:id="@+id/main_table" android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent">
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

In the second `Activity`, the `ArrayList` is being traversed to display the data in the `TableLayout`.
I guess the `ArrayList` is not being transfered properly to the next `Activity`.

```
public class two extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_two);
        Intent i = getIntent();
        ArrayList<String> al = i.getStringArrayListExtra("al");
        TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_table);
        TableRow tr_head = new TableRow(this);
        //tr_head.setId(11);
        // tr_head.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        int co=0;
        for(String k:al)
        {
            co++;
            TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
            tr.setId(co);
            tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                                   TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                   TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setText(k);
            tv.setPadding(2, 0, 5, 0);
            tr_head.addView(tv);
            tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                           TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                           TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: You've mixed up `tr_head` and `tr` inside the loop. You're adding the `TextView`s to `tr_head`, but it's never added to the `TableLayout`. You're adding `tr` to the `TableLayout`, but you're not adding the `TextView` to it. I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, exactly, but maybe you want `tr.addView(tv);` there instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ArrayList is being sent properly there is nothing wrong with that.

Also LayoutParams for TableRow isn't needed, add LayoutParams on TextView instead.

tr_head is not needed also if you have already defined Layout for TableLayout there is no need to give LayoutParams here:

```
 tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

tl.addView(tr) will do just fine.
Try using the below code, this works fine by me!

```
public class two extends AppCompatActivity {  @Override  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_two);
    Intent i = getIntent();
    ArrayList<String> al = i.getStringArrayListExtra("al");
    TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_table);
        int co=0;
    for(String k:al)
    {
        co++;
        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        tr.setId(co);
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1.0f));
        tv.setText(k);
        tv.setPadding(2, 0, 5, 0);
        tr.addView(tv);
        tl.addView(tr);
    }}}
```